# Contact Form 7 Plugin send emails to my Gmail as spam

Tags: spam, forms, contact

I just added [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) to [my site](http://widerdesign.com.tw/contact). I'm using the default configuration (didn't change any setting). The mails are classified as spam in my Gmail inbox. Is there any way of making them go directly to the inbox?

Comment: Another option is to install this wordpress plugin, will fix the issue very quickly http://www.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@janoChen,**
The problem could be that your email server is not using Domain Keys or a valid spf record

> **DomainKeys** is an e-mail authentication system that allows for incoming mail to be checked against the server it was sent from to verify that the mail has not been modified. This ensures that messages are actually coming from the listed sender and allows abusive messages to be tracked with more ease.

DomainKeys can be set up in Cpanel under Email Authentication

> **SPF** will specify which machines are authorized to send email from your domain(s). This means that only mail sent through this server will appear as valid mail from your domain(s) when the SPF records are checked.

SPF records can be set in Cpanel or by adding the record to your DNS.  A sample SPF record looks like this:

v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.17.118 a:my.servername.com ?all

This tells email servers that the specified ip address and host are permitted to send mail from my domain.

**The [Configure SMTP plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/configure-smtp/)** will set up WordPress to use SMTP authentication to send out mail.  It also has an option to use Gmail or Google Apps to send WordPress mail.

**Check the email headers to find out why your messages are going to spam**

In Gmail you can view the headers which will tell you the problem with the message by clicking the drop down arrow under replay and selecting "show original".

[image]

Here is a header example from some "Viagra" spam in my spam box:

```
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 123.238.77.28 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of chris@buymmoaccounts.com) client-ip=123.238.77.28;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 123.238.77.28 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of chris@buymmoaccounts.com) smtp.mail=chris@buymmoaccounts.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a problem with your server. If several sites are hosted on your server (shared hosting) and some of them send spam emails, it is possible the IP of your host is blacklisted.

A solution would be to use an SMTP server. This plugin will be helpful: http://www.callum-macdonald.com/code/wp-mail-smtp/. You just need to configure it so that your WordPress installation uses an SMTP server for all the emails (including those sent by Contact Form 7).

Answer (score -1):

Well that's the hard way to do it, the easy way is just click the not spam button a couple of times so google will remind your address is not spam.

If you're doing an email marketing, then it'll be a problem if your email address are marked as spam, but if your email is just used as a contact mail from wp, then simple solution is just fine.

I've had this problem a couple of times, the not spam button work ok for me

Comment: This does not address the issue at all, this is fixing a symptom, not the disease.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with WP Mail SMTP plugin. But still no success. When I use SMTP, I am getting error as "Failed to connect SMTP". I am using Google Apps for Work.